# What argument type does sscanf expect for a character class?

Tags: c, scanf

I've been trying to get `sscanf` to recognize a fairly simple format using character classes. I've noticed that when I provide `sscanf` with a `char*` to match the character class it overwrites the previous byte also as if it expected a pointer to 2 bytes.

A simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char num1;
    char num2;
    int s;
    s = sscanf("1,2", " %[01234567] , %[01234567]", &num1, &num2);
    printf("%d %c %c\n", s, num1, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output: `2 1 2`

Actual output: `2  2`

But if I replace `char` with `short` (or something else greater than a byte) then it works as expected, but I get warnings about `format expects type char*`.

What type should the argument actually be or am I making some other error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sscanf` expects a string.

```
char num1[BIG_ENOUGH], num2[BIG_ENOUGH];
s = sscanf("1,2", " %[01234567] , %[01234567]", num1, num2);
```

Of course this is completely unsafe, as the scanned string plus the terminating null may be longer than the buffer and cause a buffer overflow.

Unfortunately, the C type system can't differentiate between pointer to the beginning of a character array and a pointer to a single character, so the code in the question compiled.

Comment: Isn't it a bug in `sscanf` implementation? According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/), for `%c` "no null character is appended at the end." I didn't however find any documentation describing `%[...]`-like arguments.

Comment: I found the needed documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf. It says that "the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, **plus a terminating null byte**," which explains the behaviour.

Comment: That makes sense. I couldn't find much on `%[`. I didn't realize that character classes could match more than one character per class. I thought it was like `%c`.

Comment: If you want just one character, use `%1[`. But you still need space for the terminating null byte.